# std::fstream used but compiler throws error

Tags: c++, io

I've used

```
   using std::fstream;
```

and tried creating object of the class **ofstream**, it says

> error: **‘ofstream’** was not declared in this scope

but when specifically **using std::ofstream** is used it works fine. My question is why using the **std::fstream** is not enough since **ofstream/ifstream** are classes of this library?

Dear venerable downvoters, please provide a reason as well before downvoting so that I can improve. Thanks!

Comment: `fstream` and `ofstream` are not the same thing.

Comment: @user975989 Can you please elaborate.

Comment: When you use a `using` directive you need to name a type exactly. These two types are not one and the same.

Comment: To put it in context of the question, `using::fstream` does not use the library but the [`class fstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing the usage of `#include` and `using`. `#include` includes (amaizing isn't it?) declarations in your source file making them available. `#include <fstream>` actually declares `std::fstream` and `std::ofstream`.

`using` on the other hand imports declarations from other namespaces in the current namespace to allow usage of *unqualified* names. Here `std::ofstream` is the qualified name (includes the namespace) and the unqualified one is... `ofstream`

So if you want to use the unqualified name `ofstream`, add `using std::ofstream;` to your code.

But beware, namespaces were added to C++ to allow proper separation of declarations and avoid name clash. Excessive usage of `using` directives specifically in main namespace (the frowned upon `using namespace std;`) causes *namespace pollution* and will lead to clash at a moment...

Alternatively, you can omit the `using` directive and consistently use `std::ofstream` throughout your code.

Comment: What I am thinking is when I 'used' using fstream, I thought the material needed for ofstream was also imported as all comes under fstream header and using fstream must be having ofstream as a subset. is it wrong?